# What would cause an ASP.NET API to throw a 500 error then return 401 errors for every request after that until the app pool is recycled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

We have an ASP.NET (.NET Framework 4.7.2) that has been working fine for the past several months. We installed this at a new customer and have come across this strange issue that I can't seem to solve.

For some reason, during normal API calls, we receive a 500.0 response that takes 17 seconds to complete. After this happens every request that is sent receives a 401.0 response that takes 5 seconds to complete, even though the authorization has not changed. Everything that was previously working no longer works. The only fix is to recycle the application pool, which seems to clear the issue and service is restored.

No error is ever recorded. The event logs show nothing, IIS logs only show the 500 and subsequent 401.0 responses, and application logs don't report any kind of exception. It just simply shuts down.

Our API uses anonymous authentication. Windows authentication was turned on, so we disabled it. We found somewhere else that this error can sometimes be caused by anon authentication being set to a specific user, so we changed that to application pool identity. This was a newer version of our API, so we rolled it back to one at a different client that was not having these issues and the error persists.

I'm beyond out of ideas. We can't figure out what is going on.

This API is running on a Win2016 Server, IIS 10, latest updates. It has been rebooted several times as well.

Comment: Are you using session() anywhere? After a app-pool reset (which can occur for MANY reasons - even a code error can trigger a app-pool re-start). If the app pool re-starts, then you going to lose all session value(s). However, if you switch on sql server based session management, then the session will survive such re-starts.

Comment: 500.0 and 401.0 are typical errors generated by your web app (and its web framework), so I don't think you should waste any time there but go back to debugging source code of the web app. You can use FRT to get more hints, but I am sure the conclusion should be similar, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal No, we are not using session() anywhere currently.

Comment: Hum then not sure what to suggest. Do you have a global error trap handler routine, perhaps that could help, but I suspect you have one already.

Comment: Yes, we do. The problem is that it doesn't throw any errors when it happens. I am suspecting that it might be related to the customers AV or network security setup, but am having a difficult time getting information from them about that.

Comment: Following Lex Li's suggestion, using failed request tracing to get more information can further help you analyze and solve problems.

Comment: I had turned that on, and found that I'm getting a "timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool/may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and the max pool size was reached" error. I've increased the pool size to 3000 but it doesn't seem to have done any good. My dev team is going to start working through the code on Monday to eliminate any non-disposed connections, but I'm just trying to keep it running until we can make those changes.

Comment: I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.